# Append list elements to list of lists in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, append

Given the following lists:

```
list1 = [[1, 2],
         [3, 4],
         [5, 6],
         [7, 8]]
list2 = [10, 11, 12, 13]
```

What is the best way to change `list1` so it becomes the following list in python?

```
[[1, 2, 10],
 [3, 4, 11],
 [5, 6, 12],
 [7, 8, 13]]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `zip`:

```
[x + [y] for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
# [[1, 2, 10], [3, 4, 11], [5, 6, 12], [7, 8, 13]]
```

To modify `list1` in place, you could do:

```
for x, y in zip(list1, list2):
    x.append(y)

list1
# [[1, 2, 10], [3, 4, 11], [5, 6, 12], [7, 8, 13]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Or, a comprehension with unpacking, after `zip`ing, if you're using Python >= 3.5:

```
>>> l = [[*i, j] for i,j in zip(list1, list2)]
>>> print(l)
[[1, 2, 10], [3, 4, 11], [5, 6, 12], [7, 8, 13]]
```

Of course, if the list sizes might differ, you'd be better off using [`zip_longest` from `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) to gracefully handle the extra elements.

Answer (score -1):

You can make it this way:

```
list1 = [[1, 2],
         [3, 4],
         [5, 6],
         [7, 8]]
list2 = [10, 11, 12, 13]

def add_item_to_list_of_lists(list11, list2):
    # list1, list to add item of the second list to
    # list2, list with items to add to the first one
    for numlist, each_list in enumerate(list1):
        each_list.append(list2[numlist])

add_item_to_list_of_lists(list1, list2)
print(list1)
```

Output

```
[[1, 2, 10], [3, 4, 11], [5, 6, 12], [7, 8, 13]]
```

Comment: Why are you providing [mutable default args](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments)? Are their contents supposed to be comments instead?

Comment: Why are you using `list1[numlist]` instead of `each_list`?